# How to write the for loop in LUA?

Tags: lua

There is a demo:

```
days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday","Saturday"}

    if keyJustPressed('space') then
        for i, v in ipairs(days) do
            print(v)
            break
        end
    end
```

I want:
When pressing key "space" the first time, print "Sunday".
When pressing key "space" the second time, print "Monday".
When pressing key "space" the third time, print "Tuesday".
And so on...

How to write the for loop?
Don't worry about `keyJustPressed('space')`, it works correctly.

Comment: you don't want to know how to write a for loop as you already know that. please ask what actually you want to know to avoid confusing titles like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use a for loop here. but keep a variable that points to the current day. For example

```
index = 1
```

Then increase the index everytime you press space like this

```
if keyJustPressed('space') then
    print(days[index])
    index = index % #days + 1
end
```

`% #days` is done here so it goes back to 1 after getting to 7.
And be sure to do the `index = 1` outside of the scope where you do `keyJustPressed`, otherwise it keeps being reset to 1